# Is there a way to delay cache revalidation in service worker?

Tags: caching, service-worker, indexeddb, service-worker-events

I am currently working on performance improvements for a React-based SPA. Most of the more basic stuff is already done so I started looking into more advanced stuff such as service workers.
The app makes quite a lot of requests on each page (most of the calls are not to REST endpoints but to an endpoint that basically makes different SQL queries to the database, hence the amount of calls). The data in the DB is not updated too often so we have a local cache for the responses, but it's obviously getting lost when a user refreshes a page. This is where I wanted to use the service worker - to keep the responses either in cache store or in IndexedDB (I went with the second option). And, of course, the cache-first approach does not fit here too well as there is still a chance that the data may become stale. So I tried to implement the stale-while-revalidate strategy: fetch the data once, then if the response for a given request is already in cache, return it, but make a real request and update the cache just in case.

I tried the approach from Jake Archibald's [offline cookbook](https://web.dev/offline-cookbook/#stale-while-revalidate) but it seems like the app is still waiting for **real** requests to resolve even when there is a cache entry to return from (I see those responses in Network tab).
Basically the sequence seems to be the following: request > cache entry found! > need to update the cache > only then show the data. Doing the update immediately is unnecessary in my case so I was wondering if there is any way to delay that? Or, alternatively, not to wait for the "real" response to be resolved?

Here's the code that I currently have (`serializeRequest`, `cachePut` and `cacheMatch` are helper functions that I have to communicate with IndexedDB):

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  // some checks to get out of the event handler if certain conditions don't match...

  event.respondWith(
    serializeRequest(request).then((serializedRequest) => {
      return cacheMatch(serializedRequest, db.post_cache).then((response) => {
        const fetchPromise = fetch(request).then((networkResponse) => {
          cachePut(serializedRequest, response.clone(), db.post_cache);
          return networkResponse;
        });
        return response || fetchPromise;
      });
    })
  );
})
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Can this be due to the fact that I put stuff into IndexedDB instead of cache? I am sort of forced to use IndexedDB instead of the cache because those "magic endpoints" are POST instead of GET (because of the fact they require the body) and POST cannot be inserted into the cache...

Comment: Hmm...have you tried with [Workbox's StaleWhileRevalidate strategy](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies#stale-while-revalidate)?

Comment: Do you mean using Workbox's CacheableResponse with StaleWhileRevalidate? That could in theory be possible but I haven't found any examples for that so I went with the "classic" event interception option. Do you know where I can find more examples in addition to https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-cacheable-response?

Comment: Using it is fairly simple, see this [minimal example](https://www.charistheo.io/blog/2021/03/workbox-strategies-with-examples-and-use-cases/#stalewhilerevalidate--example). If the resources are in another origin other than from where your front-end is, only then you have to use `CacheableResponsePlugin`.

Comment: See also [this example](https://www.charistheo.io/blog/2021/03/cache-handling-with-service-workers-and-the-cache-api/#respond-from-cache-otherwise-fetch-from-network) but you may want to alter the logic to always fetch from the network and update the cache regardless of whether it was found in the cache or not.

Comment: Thank you. The second example if pretty much what I have right now for GET requests using cache. It implements stale-while-revalidate strategy. The problem is that the exact same approach does not work when I am trying to get the cached response from IndexedDB...